# Duplicate- dcount

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am importing data from Outlook and would like to only import emails where there is no duplicate in a field.

I have tried DCount, and it is working, but it will still duplicate the last record in the form. So if i import 9 emails, and hit the button again it will not import anything except the last email in the form. Not sure why that one is still being allowed to pass the code...

```
Dim Olapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim Olmapi As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Olfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim OlAccept As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim OlDecline As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim OlFailed As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim OlMail As Object 'Have to late bind as appointments e.t.c screw it up
    Dim OlItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim OlRecips As Outlook.Recipients
    Dim OlRecip As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim OlAcc As Outlook.Account
    Dim abody() As String
    Dim j As Long
    Dim SID As Variant
Dim stLinkCriteria As Variant
Dim rsc As DAO.Recordset
    Dim reQuest, strRequestType, StartDate, strExPdate, strMunicipality, strAddNumber, strAddName, strCrossStreet, strTypeWork, strExtWork, strExcavator, strExcPhone, strExcCell, strExcEmail, strWorkFor As String
'Create a connection to outlook
    Set Olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Olmapi = Olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'Open the inbox
    Set Olfolder = Olmapi.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set OlItems = Olfolder.Items
'Reset the olitems object otherwise new incoming mails and moving mails get missed
    Set OlItems = Olfolder.Items
    For Each OlMail In OlItems
'For each mail in the collection check the subject line and process accordingly
        If OlMail.UnRead = True Or OlMail.UnRead = False Then
        'If OlMail.Sender = "nj@occinc.com" Then
           ' OlMail.UnRead = False 'Mark mail as read


Set rsc = Me.RecordsetClone
If Not IsNull(Me.Requestnumber.Value) Then


SID = Me.Requestnumber.Value
stLinkCriteria = "[requestnumber]=" & "'" & SID & "'"

        If DCount("requestnumber", "import table", stLinkCriteria) > 0 Then
        'Undo duplicate entry
      Me.Undo

     End If
                  End If
                  Set rsc = Nothing

            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
            abody = Split(OlMail.Body, Chr(13) & Chr(10))
            For j = 0 To UBound(abody)

                If abody(j) <> "" Then     
                    If InStr(1, abody(j), "Request No.:", 1) Then
                        reQuest = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Request No.:") + 13)
                        Me.Requestnumber = reQuest
                    End If
                    If InStr(1, abody(j), "***", 1) Then
                        strRequestType = Trim(Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "***") + 4))
                        strRequestType = ParseWord(strRequestType, 1, , True, True)
                        If strRequestType = "R" Then
                            Me.RequestType = "ROUTINE"
                        ElseIf strRequestType = "E" Then
                            Me.RequestType = "EMERGENCY"
                        ElseIf strRequestType = "U" Then
                            Me.RequestType = "UPDATE"
                        End If
                    End If
                    If InStr(1, abody(j), "Start Date/Time:", 1) Then
                        StartDate = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Start Date/Time:") + 17)
                        Me.DueDate = ParseWord(StartDate, 1, , True, True)
                    End If
                    If InStr(1, abody(j), "Expiration Date:", 1) Then
                        strExPdate = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Expiration Date:") + 17)
                        If strExPdate = " " Then
                            Me.ExPdate = Date
                        Else
                            Me.ExPdate = strExPdate
                        End If
                    End If
                    If InStr(1, abody(j), "Municipality:", 1) Then
                        strMunicipality = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Municipality:") + 14)
                        Me.JobAddressTown = strMunicipality
                    End If
                    If InStr(1, abody(j), "Street:", 1) Then
                        strAddNumber = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Street:") + 8)
                        Me.JobAddressNumber = ParseWord(strAddNumber, 1, , True, True)
                        Me.JobAddressName = ParseWord(strAddNumber, 2, , True, True) & " " & ParseWord(strAddNumber, 3, , True, True)
                    End If

                    If InStr(1, abody(j), "Nearest Intersection:", 1) Then
                        strCrossStreet = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Nearest Intersection:") + 21)
                        Me.SideStreet1 = Trim(strCrossStreet)
                    End If

                    If InStr(1, abody(j), "Type of Work:", 1) Then
                        strTypeWork = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Type of Work:") + 14)
                        Me.TypeofWork = Trim(strTypeWork)
                    End If

If InStr(1, abody(j), "Extent of Work:", 1) Then
    strExtWork = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Extent of Work:") + 16)
   Me.ExtentofWork = Trim(strExtWork)
End If
                          If InStr(1, abody(j), "Working For:", 1) Then
                      strWorkFor = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Excavator:") + 14)
                        Me.Excavator = Trim(strExcavator)
                    End If

                    If InStr(1, abody(j), "Excavator:", 1) Then
                        strExcavator = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Working For:") + 11)
                        Me.workingfor = Trim(strWorkFor)
                    End If

                    If InStr(1, abody(j), "Phone:", 1) Then
                        strExcPhone = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Phone:") + 7)
                        Me.ExcavatorPhone = Trim(ParseWord(strExcPhone, 1, , True, True))
                    End If

                    If InStr(1, abody(j), "Cellular:", 1) Then
                        strExcCell = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Cellular:") + 10)
                        Me.excavatorcell = Trim(strExcCell)
                    End If

                    If InStr(1, abody(j), "Email:", 1) Then
                        strExcEmail = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Email:") + 7)
                        Me.ExcavatorEmail = Trim(strExcEmail)
                    End If
                End If
                 End If
```

Below is the a sample of the email that I am importing:

```
Transmit:  Date: 

*** R O U T I N E         *** Request No.: 123456789

Operators Notified: 


Start Date/Time:    01/01/18   At 00:15  Expiration Date: 01/01/18 

Location Information: 
County:     Municipality: 
Subdivision/Community:  
Street:               0 FAKE ST
Nearest Intersection: FAKE ST
Other Intersection:    
Lat/Lon: 
Type of Work: REPAIR  
Block:                Lot:                Depth: 2FT 

Extent of Work:  BEGINS 53FT W OF C/L OF INTERSECTION AND EXTENDS 785FT
 W.  MARK A 3FT RADIUS OF POLE NUMBERS 000/000, 000/000

Remarks:  
 Working For Contact:  NO ONE

Working For: NO ONE
Address:     123 FAKE ST
City:        SPRINGFIELD
Phone:       555-555-5555   Ext:  

Excavator Information: 
Caller:      NO ONE
Phone:       555-555-5555   Ext:  

Excavator:   NO ONE

Address:     123 FAKE ST
City:        SPRINGFIELD
Phone:       555-555-5555   Ext:          Fax:  
Cellular:     
Email:       EMAIL@EMAIL.COM

End Request
```

Comment: Not seeing import code. What event is posted code in? Is requestnumber field set as unique?

Comment: Request number is not set to unique. Here is the import code ```If InStr(1, abody(j), "Request No.:", 1) Then reQuest = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Request No.:") + 13) Me.Requestnumber = reQuest```

Comment: Should requestnumber be unique in [import table]? Could be better naming convention: [RequestNumber], [tblImport]. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Should edit question to include additional info so readers don't have to wade through comments.

Comment: Example of data would be helpful. Your comment shows string manipulation but that is not code to import from external source. So how are you 'importing' - are you linking to Outlook folder?

Comment: OK i have updated the original post with the full code and a sample of an email that i am importing

Comment: Posted code should not compile - missing `Next` line for each `For`. Code would be easier to read if you used consistent indentation. Variables without explicitly declared type default to Variant. Doesn't matter if they are all on a line that ends with `As String`, only the last variable is a String and others are Variant.

Comment: Trying to follow code logic. You test for existing RequestNumber and attempt to 'Undo' something but then code continues on to a NewRecord row and enters data anyway. Exactly what data entry are you trying to 'Undo' - what input has user done?

Comment: the code does compile- everything works fine, except the dcount. I am trying to check the request number on the sample email i provided and if that number already exists in my database i dont want that email to import. it is working ok except that the newest existing entry in the database will still be allowed for some reason. everything else does not import over.

Comment: Posted code is still missing `Next` lines. Didn't really answer my question - What exactly is being 'Undone'? Form is bound to `[Import table]`? RecordsetClone serves no purpose. Have you step-debugged?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this revised code. It first extracts RequestNumber from email body then searches for that data in table and if not found, a new record is created.

```
For Each OlMail In OlItems
    If OlMail.UnRead = True Or OlMail.UnRead = False Then
        reQuest = ""
        If InStr(1, OlMail.Body, "Request No.:", 1) Then
            reQuest = Mid(OlMail.Body, InStr(OlMail.Body, "Request No.:") + 13, 9)
        End If
        If reQuest <> "" Then
            If DCount("requestnumber", "import table", "[requestnumber]='" & reQuest & "'") = 0 Then
                'save data to record
                DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
                Me.RequestNumber = request
                'extract rest of data
                abody = Split(OlMail.Body, Chr(13) & Chr(10))
                For j = 0 To UBound(abody)
                    If abody(j) <> "" Then
                        '...
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```